# Как последнюю латинскую букву в слове сделать заглавной

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как регулярным выражением сменить регистр последней латинской буквы в слове?

**Пример текста**:

```
cloud
```

**Желаемый результат**:

```
clouD
```

Comment: Например так ([a-z])($|\s) замена \U\1\2

С русскими не будет работать

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: То есть вам не нужна поддержка русских букв?

Comment: русских букв нет, только латынь. Вы мне очень помогли. мысленно желаю удачи)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать следующее регулярные выражения:

```
[a-z](?!\S)
[a-z]\b
```

Замените на

```
\U$0
```

Шаблон `[a-z]` находит латинские строчные буквы, блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!\S)` проверяет, нет ли сразу после текщей позиции символа, отличного от пробельного символа, а `\b` находит границу слова.

Оператор `\U` приводит целое совпадение (`$0`) к верхнему регистру.

См. тест и настройки на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]